# Fabricating an APD (Avalanche photo-diode) with a twist

Tags: electronics

Instead of **one n-layer and three different types of p-layers**, we have been given **one p-layer and three different types of n-layers** for fabricating an APD. In other words:
(a) Replacing the n+ layer with p+ layer, and vice versa.
(b) Replacing the p-type layer with n-type layer, and
(c) Relpacing a lightly doped p-type intrinsic layer (I-layer) with lightly doped p-type intrinsic layer in the given diagram.
**Q1. Would we be able to successfully fabricate an APD?

Q2. If so, then what physical mechanism of this new photo-diode will be?**

[image]

Fig. 1: Real avalanche photo diode block diagram.

Comment: Why do you think they would be substantially different?

Comment: Think about the types of carriers that would be avalanching.

Comment: Q1 is an engineering question, not physics.